# SQL Query that merges rows with junction table

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have the following database strucuture

1 Table named Books (BookId,Title)
1 Table named Authors (AuthorId,AuthorName)
1 Junction Table named BooksAuthors (BookID,AuthorID) with relations to the other 2 tables

i'm using this query:

```
   Select
  Books.BookId,
  Books.Title,
  Authors.AuthorName
From
  (Books Inner Join
  BooksAuthors On BooksAuthors.BookId = Books.BooksId) Inner Join
  Authors On BooksAuthors.AuthorId = Authors.AuthorId
```

I get something like this:

```
BookId         Title            AuthorName
001           Title1            Name1
001           Title1            Name2
001           Title1            Name3
002           Title2            Name5
002           Title2            Name6
```

I wonder is it would be possible to do a query that would return something like this:

```
BookId         Title            AuthorName
001           Title1            Name1;Name2;Name3
002           Title2            Name5;Name6
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The database is in ms access

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` for that

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Books.BookId,
  Books.Title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Authors.AuthorName,'; ')
FROM
  (Books Inner Join
  BooksAuthors On BooksAuthors.BookId = Books.BooksId) Inner Join
  Authors On BooksAuthors.AuthorId = Authors.AuthorId
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `group by`

Comment: Also, you are missing the `separator` in `group_concat`.

Answer (score 0):

This include the `GROUP BY` for `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Books.BookId,
  Books.Title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Authors.AuthorName SEPARATOR ';')
FROM Books
  INNER JOIN BooksAuthors USING (BookId)
  INNER JOIN Authors USING (AuthorId)
GROUP BY Books.BookId, Books.Title
```

**EDIT**: Fixing `SEPARATOR` in `GROUP_CONCAT`.  Also, this answer assumes MySQL.

Comment: thx for the reply but i forgot to say that i am using the query in a vb.net project and the group_concat() doens't seem to be supported any alternative